# Optimized Hit Testing in Collection of WPF Geometry

Tags: c#, wpf, c#-4.0

I have an abstractly large IEnumerable container of Wpf Geometry objects; the boundary of the Geometry objects are non-trivial; they don't represent simple geometric shapes like rectangles or circles, they are complex polygons. The List will never change once initially populated.

I then have a point, and I want to determine which Geometry contains that point.

```
List<Geometry> list = getList();
var point = new Point(x,y);

list.Any(y => y.Bounds.Contains(point) && y.FillContains(point));
```

This code works, but its generally slow. The initial Bounds check is a short circuit that ends up being about 50% faster than without it. I think the next layer of complexity is to setup some sort of pre-rendered hit-map Dictionary.

Is there anything better that already exists in WPF to accomplish this task in a more performance oriented fashion?

Comment: Did you try to add all those Geometries to a GeometryGroup and then call the GeometryGroup's FillContains method?

Comment: That only tells me if a Geometry exists at that point, not specifically which one.  I did try some things with the GeometryGroup. I created a list of 1000 geometries with random size.  the GeometryGroup was almost 10 times slower.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up creating a custom class that used the bounding box of each Geometry to perform a tiered lookup. The first tier used the simple bounding box calculation to narrow the list of Geometry objects that were necessary to search.

Each "bucket" was calculated using the average size of all Geometries in the collection. This has problems for the general case, but given that most of my Geometries are roughly the same size, this was a decent solution.

Answer (score -3):

MSDN is best

1. [How to: Hit Test Geometry in a Visual](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms750584%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)
2. [How to: Hit Test Using Geometry as a Parameter](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms748343%28v=vs.100%29.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396)